# GTM Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM's "Custom HTML Tag" option with the my below code but it is giving me the following error when I try to publish it: Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

I've seen other threads where it looks like GTM doesn't support or recognize certain tag attributes. I have tested my code, and no error prompts show up in the console either. It is a standard bootstrap modal:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.innerHTML);

  var testtip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  testtip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.innerHTML;
}

function outFunc() {
  var testtip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  testtip.innerHTML = "Copy";
}

$("#myModal").modal();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif
}

.modal-login {
  color: #636363;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-image: none!important
}

.modal-login .modal-content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 586px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: #eaebeb;
  background-image: url(https://media-services.dcm-inc.com/couponsites/static/resources/img/festival.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.modal-login .modal-header {
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 130px
}

.modal-login img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%
}

.modal-login .form-group {
  position: relative
}

.modal-login h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.modal-login i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  top: 11px;
  font-size: 18px
}

.modal-login .form-control {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .modal-login .form-control {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%
  }
}

.modal-login .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #fcda7b
}

.modal-login .btn,
.modal-login .form-control {
  min-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px
}

.modal-login .hint-text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px
}

.modal-login .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px
}

.button,
.modal-login .btn {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fcda7b 0, #fd5c88 100%);
  border: none;
  line-height: normal
}

.modal-login .custom {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .modal-login .custom {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%
  }
}

.modal-login .custom-social {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%
}

.modal-login .btn:focus,
.modal-login .btn:hover {
  opacity: .7
}

.trigger-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px auto
}

.contest-social {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.modal-login .fa:hover {
  opacity: .7
}

.modal-login .contest-social-facebook {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fcda7b 0, #fd5c88 100%)!important;
  color: #fff
}

.modal-login .contest-social-twitter {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fcda7b 0, #fd5c88 100%)!important;
  color: #fff
}

.modal-login .contest-social-youtube {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fcda7b 0, #fd5c88 100%)!important;
  color: #fff
}

.modal-login .contest-social-instagram {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fcda7b 0, #fd5c88 100%)!important;
  color: #fff
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex
}

.flexC {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap
}

.modal-title img {
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ddd
}

.modal-title p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  max-width: 300px;
  color: #000
}

.ccme {
  color: #fd5c88
}

.codelinkbox {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  position: relative
}

.codeValue {
  border: 2px dashed currentColor;
  font-size: 28px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px!important;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000
}

.buttonBtn.copy {
  background-color: currentColor;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
  -o-transition: all .3s linear;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0
}

.buttonBtn.copy:hover {
  background: #6ba62c;
  color: #fff
}

.copy span {
  color: #fff
}

.m1 {
  margin: 1rem auto
}

.txtC {
  text-align: center
}

.buttonBtn {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 54px;
  min-width: 180px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 54px
}

.arrRight {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700
}

.arrRight:after {
  content: '\2192';
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff
}

.emailIcon {
  width: 24px;
  max-width: 24px;
  margin: 0 5px
}

.termsto {
  margin: 3rem 0
}

.sendemail {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 10px 0
}

@media all and (max-width:540px) {
  .modal-title {
    text-align: center
  }
  .modal-login .modal-header {
    margin-top: 40px
  }
}

.testtip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.testtip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 120%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.testtip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.testtip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%7CVarela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-login border">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title">
          <div class="flexC">
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/csnetworkco/image/upload/c_scale,h_150,w_150/csnimages/Noon_568012.jpg" alt="Noon Discount Code" title="Noon Discount Code" width="150" height="150" loading="lazy">
            <p>Up To 70% Off Sale + 10% Off Using Noon Coupon Code</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="codelinkbox flexC m1">
            <div id="myInput" class="codeValue">YB26</div>
            <div class="testtip">
              <button class="buttonBtn copy ccme" onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()"><span id="myTooltip">Copy</span></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row termsto">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <p><strong>Things to remember:</strong></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Don't forget to paste the code in the checkout during the purchase</li>
              <li>Get 10% Off for New Customers & 5% Off for Returning Customers. </li>
              <li>Code Usage: 2 times per customer.</li>
              <li>Always contact our customer support team if there is any issues</li>
              <li>You can always share the code</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 txtC ">
            <a href="https://www.noon.com/uae-en/"><button class="buttonBtn ccme button" id=""><span class="arrRight">VISIT SITE </span></button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, who was the joker who wroted that error message. Ban `innerHTML` everywhere and try again.

Comment: I removed all the js and css and just tried to publish the HTML modal, it is still giving me the same error, it seems something form the HTML is not acceptable to GTM

Comment: I found what the issue was, in the img tag I was adding an attribute loading="lazy" due to which the invalid HTML CSS or JS error was being thrown

They really need to highlight what part of the code is the problem

Thanks anyways @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the issue was, in the img tag I was adding an attribute loading="lazy" due to which the invalid HTML CSS or JS error was being thrown

They really need to highlight what part of the code is the problem

I removed the above mentioned attribute and am now able to publish the tag